# When i was a GATSBY Build, i get 2 errors

Tags: javascript, gatsby, gatsby-plugin, gatsby-plugin-mdx

[This is my Gatsby Blog GitHub Link](https://github.com/fsk/fsk.io)

When i work build i get 2 errors.

1. `The field "Mdx.excerpt." was explicitly defined as non-nullable via the schema customization API (by yourself or a plugin/theme). This means that this field is not optional and you have to define a value. If this is not your desired behavior and you defined the schema yourself, go to "createTypes" in gatsby-node.js. If you're using a plugin/theme, you can learn more here on how to fix field types:`

2. `An error occurred during parallel query running.`

When i was get build, gatsby give me some suggestions for my errors in this terminal.

[Suggestion For first error](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/graphql-data-layer/schema-customization#fixing-field-types)

[Suggestion for Second Error](https://gatsby.dev/pqr-feedback)

How can i these fix.?

For the run my project, in this terminal

First step: `npm install`

Second Step: `npm run dev`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to have an excerpt in your MDX file(s)

---

```
---
```

`title:` Building with Gatsby
`author:` Jay Gatsby
`excerpt:` This is my excerpt

```
---
```

---

That may solve both problems since the second is referencing a query as well.